# Java. Trying to split an array of legnth 4 into Arrays of index (0,1) (1,2) (2,3)

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse

My main method is already complete and correct. In main "isEverywhere" is called upon and that is what I am trying to complete. I need "isEverywhere" to separate an array into 3 sub Arrays for example arr1 {1,2,1,3} would need to be {1,2} {2,1} {1,3}. Then I need something I believe a loop that will go through each array and search for a 1. If there is a 1 in the sub Array it should print true and if there isn't it should print false which would only be the case for arr3.

```
public class TinyCode3 {
    public boolean isEverywhere(int[] nums, int value) {
      boolean b = true;
      // YOUR CODE HERE

  public static void main(String [] args) {
        TinyCode3 tc = new TinyCode3();
        int val = 1;
    int [] arr1 = {1,2,1,3};
    boolean answer = tc.isEverywhere(arr1,val);
        System.out.println("Expected true, got " + answer);

        int []arr2 = {2,1,2,1};
        answer = tc.isEverywhere(arr2,val);
        System.out.println("Expected true, got " + answer);

       int [] arr3 = {3,1,2,2};
       answer = tc.isEverywhere(arr3,val);
       System.out.println("Expected false, got " + answer);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps something like this:

```
public boolean isEverywhere(int[] nums, int value) {

    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length - 1; i++) {
        if (nums[i] != value && nums[i + 1] != value) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Since each of the sub arrays are made up by i and i+1 (ie. the current number and the number after it), I use a for loop to check each pair of {i,i+1}, and returns false as soon as neither contains the desired value

Comment: thank you it worked. I'm new to this and I was just wondering if you could explain which part of the code is splitting the array because that's what I couldn't figure out. Thank you so much

Comment: does i = 0 mean it equals the index 0?

Comment: I've added some explanation to the answer.
i=0 means it will start with 0, as array indexes starts with 0 (rather than 1).

Comment: Thanks again homie @ndlu